# How can I uncheck checkbox fields during form's validation?

Tags: forms

We have a Drupal 9 custom validaton hanlder where we need to remove all checkboxes from a multi-value term reference field.

I can clear/change other field types but not this one.

We tried the following code, and other variations.

```php
  $form_state->setValue('field_region', []);
```

The values always retain even though `getValue()` for the field shows as cleared in the validation function.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: When I set the field to an empty array it unchecks all checkboxes on the saved entity, for a reference field configured with the *Check Boxes* widget. To find the error I think you need to look into the variables. Things might be different in your form. The loop by the way has no function, as the code is written now you can remove it.

Comment: @4uk4 - thank you. Yep, that loop for part of another attempt. I've removed it and the values still do not clear when uses in a custom validator.  I've updated the question. Any ideas?

Comment: @4uk4 - crap, should have noted that we're testing with the "preview" function which runs the validator but doesn't seem to save the cleared values to the form when returning from the preview.